# opencv SVM doesn't work with scaled features

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

I'm trying to use the SVM in OpenCV 2.4.9, and I'm having a problem implementing feature scaling.  I'm running the source code featured in the tutorial "Introduction to Support Vector Machines":

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ml/introduction_to_svm/introduction_to_svm.html

When I just copy-paste the code and run it, it works just fine, displaying this:

[image]

I then attempt to normalize the features to [0,1] by making 2 modifications:

1. adding `trainingDataMat /= 512.f;` before training the SVM (thus normalizing the training data)
2. modifying the prediction step to `float response = SVM.predict(sampleMat/512.f);` (thus normalizing the test data).

After doing this, it predicts all values to be the same class, producing this image:

[image]

What am I missing? is there some additional step to implementing feature normalization that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Do all your columns/features go from 0 to 512?

Comment: Tell you what, not regards just this question, OpenCV's SVM is _not good_.

Comment: And, that is not how features are normalised (usually). Although, I don't see how a simple scaling by a constant should have any effect on classification. Have you checked the prediction responses numerically?

Comment: @carlosdc This code produces 4 training data points with 2 features and 2 classes, trains a linear SVM, and then predicts the class of every point on a 512x512 grid (producing the images above, with the training points marked as circles). The features themselves are `float` values ranging from 0 through 511.

Comment: @a-Jays I was originally scaling the features to [-1 1], but I simplified it to the above scheme before asking the question so my code would be as similar to the original as possible. Regarding checking the responses, apart from the parameter sweep that the code runs (producing the images posted), I also checked the responses in debug mode. They matched the graphical output.  Was there another method of checking responses you had in mind?

Comment: The value of the variable `response`. Is it same for a particular sample in both (scaled, and non-scaled) cases? It may be that there's a problem only in the drawing part..

Comment: @a-Jays The value of `response` matches the drawn value in every case. I checked this using both `printf` and debugging.

Comment: After a bit of tinkering, I discovered that if I normalize features to the range [0 1000] the SVM works just fine. I then noticed that if I normalize to [0 3] the SVM draws the decision boundary in [the wrong place](http://i.imgur.com/nwHuNXf.png). This makes me think that the code for the SVM has an integer casting somewhere that it shouldn't, but I have neither the time nor the expertise to investigate that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround that produces the desired behavior, but I must admit I'm not certain *why* it works.

The regularization parameter `C` was unspecified in both of the trials above, so it defaulted to 1. However, if I added a line in the scaled version to specify it as 512 (i.e. the value by which I divided my features during the scaling step), the SVM worked fine!

What I don't understand is why a regularization term being too small can cause misclassification of the training data, seeing as the training points are linearly separable in this case. My understanding is that misclassification of linearly-separable training data is usually a result of `C` being too *large*.